# Bitcoin sell or buy Monitor with Colours( in cmd/win10)

Tags: python, bitcoin

[This is my goal ;)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HYNFJ.png)
I try to write a Python Script which prints the Bitcoin Price and set the colours green or red (higher price -->Green/ falling price --> Red) .

now, its prints all in red (Fore.RED)But how can i write the code?

if Pricefloat higher then xxx print green else: red

many thanks for help... :)

code:

```
import requests, json
    from time import sleep
    from colorama import init, Fore, Back, Style
    def getBitcoinPrice():
        URL = 'https://www.bitstamp.net/api/ticker/'
        try:
            r = requests.get(URL)
            priceFloat = float(json.loads(r.text)['last'])
            return priceFloat
        except requests.ConnectionError:
            print ("Error querying Bitstamp API")
    while True:
        init(convert=True)
        print (Fore.RED + "Bitstamp last price: $" + str(getBitcoinPrice()) + "/BTC")
```

Comment: You need to fix your indentation.

Comment: Also, ```if Pricefloat higher then xxx print green else: red``` is almost valid Python.I imagine your ```json.loads(r.text)``` will have other keys, perhaps such as a percentage which is ```+``` or ```-``` you could use in the if statement.

Comment: i've tried now : if priceFloat > 8000:
        print ("Bitstamp last price: $" + str(getBitcoinPrice()) + "/BTC")  but it wont work.. i think i missed some parse of the json or something. im sry im a noob in python& json :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In your `while` loop, I think what you want is:

```
price = getBitcoinPrice()

if price > 8000: # Or whatever price
    print (Fore.RED + "Bitstamp last price: $" + str(price) + "/BTC")
else:
    print (Fore.GREEN + "Bitstamp last price: $" + str(price) + "/BTC")
```